# js code not stored in database currectly

Tags: php, javascript, encoding

I'm trying to let the admin store a js code with one of the plugins I developed.
For some reason `for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)` stores as `for(i = 0; i &lt; 5; i++)`.
I'm using `sanitize_textarea_field` to store the field from a textarea. Also, I've tried `esc_js` and `json_encode`, which did not worked for me also.

How can I fix this?

Comment: sanitize_textarea_field uses sanitize_text_field which converts angle brackets to HTML entities. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/. Have you tried removing that filter?

Answer (score -1):

If you search WordPress core for `&lt;` or `&gt;` you will find the function `_wp_specialchars` in `/wp-includes/formatting.php`

Then if you search for `_wp_specialchars` you will see it is used in `esc_js` (as well as `esc_html` and `esc_attr`) so do not use `esc_js`, escaping is mostly for output anyway.

Further search results show that in `/wp-includes/default-filters.php` that `_wp_specialchars` is added to multiple filters with a priority of 30. So what you would need to do is find out which filter is being applied to your text area value before saving, so that then you can do this before saving:

```
remove_filter('NAME_OF_FILTER_HOOK', '_wp_specialchars', 30);
```

It is hard to be more specific than that without the actual code used, but this should give you enough clues to find what you need.